Discrete components motor driver or integrated solution
Is there any reason for someone to implement a stepper (or DC) motor driving circuit with discrete components such as ZXMHC3F381N8 and external MOSFETs, resistors, snubber circuits, flyback diodes etc., instead of using an integrated solution? The ICs (I am looking at TI's DRV series) also include some nice-to-haves like OCP, OV/UVLO, thermal shutdown, and, on top of these, they take up a lot less space.
My specific application is to drive a solenoid valve and I am using "Using Motor Drivers to Drive Solenoids" (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae59a/slvae59a.pdf?ts=1713874614363&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) TI report as a guide.
If I would consider the discrete component approach, would it be possible to include some OCP against shoot-through and OV/UVLO circuits or is it getting too complex? I am thinking of a PTC fuse but I am not sure whether that's enough or at least acceptable

If an off-the-shelf solution is available, go for it.  Discrete component approaches are still very useful in some applications:

When you are running at high temperature.  Thermal shutdown is a negative here.
When you are running at very high power.  You can keep the temperature rise from your switching elements away from the low-power electronics.
When you are running at very high current or very high voltage.  The lead spacing and ratings of the all-in-one parts usually won't suffice.

Even when discrete switching components have to be used, there are often controller parts that can drive them while providing the features you mention.

so, regarding low-power applications like 5-12V it doesn't worth the complexity and space to use the discrete components approach?


Is there any reason for someone to implement a stepper (or DC) motor driving circuit with discrete components

Curiosity, "just because", a semi-fetish of discrete parts, supply chain considerations... to name a few.
Your question would be more focused if you provided the context to which it applies. Are we talking about a hobby? A job? If it's a job, is it design of mainstream consumer gear, mainstream instrumentation, or boutique/oddity stuff? And so on. If you mentioned a few very specific circumstances in your question that are of interest to you, I'll gladly edit the answer to address those then.
At the most basic level: the mere possibility of doing it is enough reason for plenty of people :)

the specific application is driving a stepper motor at low voltages, 12V more specifically. The motor will be used for a physics experiment, so reliability is an important feature. The motor draws about 1-1.2A.

Well, for something like a generic little solenoid, I would be fine with a plain switch driven from an MCU.
But this already depends on many things:

Is the solenoid internal, a known and consistent load?
Is it big enough that protection, reduced drive, limiting, etc. is desirable/required?  (Or perhaps it's small, but battery-powered, so the efficiency gain is relevant.)
Does it need (or can it support) controls, such as proportional (voltage or current), constant-flux drive, etc.?

If it's an external load, likely not only is protection desirable, but slew rate limiting or filtering as well.
Note that the same concerns go for anything else electromechanical: relay, motor, speaker, etc.  And to a certain extent, anything you'd be switching (on/off, or PWM), like an adjustable power supply output.
For any of these cases, if the number of desired features outstrips the will to do it discrete (where "will" is probably measured in dollars of production cost, engineering time, and project timeline), then that's the best solution to choose.
Or more appropriately: whichever route is overall cheapest while meeting the requirements.
A simple on-off with a transistor and nothing else, well maybe a clamp diode, is hard to argue with, assuming you don't need any other features.
Implementing, basically any protective feature, with discrete circuitry, is quickly a Sisyphean effort.  Linear current limiting is fine (see also: LED driving), as long as it doesn't need to dissipate too much power of course (heatsinking quickly gets bulky and expensive).  But doing it as a switching system, plus time or temperature dependent function, plus bidirectional drive (e.g. latching solenoid, PMDC motor, etc.)... it quickly adds up to dozens of transistors at least.
You can get a lot of help with an MCU, assuming you have the spare pins to implement a protective system (e.g. timer output, ADC input for current or voltage sense, etc.) -- but this turns the time spent designing an analog circuit, and the accompanying layout area and component cost, into a pile of code that not only has to be written, but tested, debugged, maintained, and eventually ported as time goes on.  It's much easier to ensure correctness of a relatively simple analog circuit (but, even then--) than a software stack you can't prove anything about (except for the few that do, or given enough time to work through a novel proof, but... yeah).  But it's far, far easier to use a chip where that's (hopefully) been done for you already.
You always need slew rate limiting or filtering, of course, when cables leave the board and switching is employed; an IC can't address every possible EMC issue.  But replacing all the rest of the circuitry with a little IC is definite value.
